# Oracle / SQL Error Invalid Identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having a problem with a `FOREIGN KEY`. I'm always getting

```
FOREIGN KEY (STUDID)
            *

ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00904: "STUDID": invalid identifier
```

Comment: The behavior you are observing is expected. In order to add a foreign key constraint, the column(s) being referenced in the constraint must exist. If you add the column, e.g. `ALTER TABLE SUBJECT ADD STUDID NUMBER(10) COMMENT 'fk ref student.studid'`, then the statement that adds the foreign key constraint will succeed. That fixes the error, but see the answer from Ditto: this looks way more like a many-to-many relationship, i.e. a subject should be allowed to be related to more than one student. But if you want a student related to at most one subject, then add `SUBJECTID` column to `STUDENT`

Answer (score 1):

You have no field called `STUDID` in your `SUBJECT` table.  Looks like you're trying to create a foreign key on a field that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Carson is correct - it seems like you are trying to build a relationship between Students and Subjects. Typically this is a many to many relationship, and would likely require a third, middle table to link them.

Think

"A Student can be enrolled to many subjects."

"A Subject can have many Students enrolled."

So you need a middle table with both `STUDID` and `SUBJECTID` columns, and **that** table would have 2 FKs declared, pointing to the other tables.

[edit] of course, that's the whole 3rd normal form thing .. you may or may not want/need to denormalize at some point, but that's a different discussion ;) [/edit]